# How do I set a different API contract to be used in Visual Studio for a Universal App?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've retargeted my C++/CX UWP project to the latest Windows version (10.0.10586) available to me. However, under references, the Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract version shows 2.0.0.0, the latest is 3.0.0.0 introduced in 10.0.14393.0. I need to use the features in 3.0.0.0, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to use it. I've looked through the .vcxproj, and the appxmanifest and I can't find anything relevant. There's nothing I can find in the GUI either. How do I change the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the target version in the project properties.

In the Project Properties editor it's in the config tab's Target Platform Version:
[image]

In the vcproj it's the WindowsTargetPlatformVersion:

```
   <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
   <WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

You'll need to have the 14393 SDK installed from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk . If Visual Studio thinks 10586 is the latest then you probably don't have the updated SDK. You should also make sure you have the latest update to Visual Studio (2015 Update 3 or 2017 RC)

Comment: I'm an idiot. For some reason in my mind I thought 10586 was a bigger number than 14393, possibly because 5 > 4. I've wasted an hour and a half on it and only realized when I read the second to last sentence on your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @justanotherxl You're not the only idiot.  I've just done it again for a fourth time.  For some reason I always read 10586 as higher than 14393. Oh the humanity!